# How to feed a list of lists as an argument into a Robot Framework Test Template

Tags: list, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have the template keyword for my "do any combination" test, where ${labels} is a list and ${versions} is a list of lists:

```
TT Process Instance Version Search
    [Arguments]     ${labels}    ${versions}
    Login
    Process Instance Version Search     ${labels}    ${versions}
```

Then I create a test-suite file and place the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template   TT Process Instance Version Search


*** Variables ***
@{ProcessVersions} =   ${Process0}     ${Process1}     ${Process2}
@{SingleVersion} =  ${Process2}
@{Process0} =   1   2
@{Process1} =   3   test_version
@{Process2} =   1

@{SingleProcessLabel} =  Label1
@{ProcessLabels} =  Label1     Label2   Label3

    *** Test Cases ***                                     
Single Instance Version for a Single Process     ${SingleProcessLabel}   ${SingleVersion}
Distinct Instance Versions for Multiple Processes    ${ProcessLabels}  ${ProcessVersions}
```

The error message I get is **"List variable '@{versions}' has no item in index 0."**

I played a lot with this, including using embedded arguments, and the only way I managed fixing it, is providing $versions directly as a global variable. My code works fine with global variables, but I have to change data manually. What I really need is implement data-driven design.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions and help!

Comment: It would help if you could reduce all of that code down to a single file with as few lines as possible. It's hard to wade through that large description. My guess is, this could be reduced down to maybe a couple dozen lines of code. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Sorry, if this is too long. It's just an example of the specific case I am working on. The question is:  How to feed list of lists as an argument into a Test template?

Comment: If that is your real question, then edit your question and remove all of the unnecessary code. However, that question is very unclear, since the answer to "how do I past a list of lists" is to simply create a list of lists and then pass it like any other argument. Robot has no problem passing lists of lists, but I suspect you mean something more. Are you asking how to take a list of lists and treat each element of a sublist as an argument (ie: to flatten the list of lists into a single list of arguments)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a comment to the question you wrote:

> The question is: How to feed list of lists as an argument into a Test template?

The answer to that is documented in the robot framework user guide, in the section titled [List Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables). When calling a keyword, if you use a `$` in front of the variable, the variable will be treated as a list object. If you use `@`, the variable will be split into multiple arguments.

When writing a keyword that accepts arguments, the same is true. If you want a single argument, use a `$` for the argument variable. If you want to collect all arguments as a list, use `@`.

Here is a test that shows a couple of examples:

```
*** Variables ***
@{numbers}    1    2    3
@{letters}    a    b    c    d
@{listoflists}    ${numbers}    ${letters}

*** Keywords ***
Accept list of lists as single arg
    [Arguments]         ${arguments}
    length should be    ${arguments}       2
    length should be    ${arguments[0]}    3
    length should be    ${arguments[1]}    4

Accept multiple args
    [Arguments]         @{arguments}
    length should be    ${arguments}       2
    length should be    ${arguments[0]}    3
    length should be    ${arguments[1]}    4


*** Test cases ***
Pass list of lists as single argument
    Accept list of lists as single arg       ${listoflists}

Pass list of lists as multiple arguments
    Accept multiple args    @{listoflists}
    Accept multiple args    ${numbers}    ${letters}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your help. Isn't it exactly what I am doing - passing the list @{ProcessLabels} and the list of lists @{ProcessVersions} as single arguments: ${ProcessLabels} and ${ProcessVersions}? I have no trouble doing that when I use global variables - the issue is when I try to use a test template.

Comment: @emi: I don't know. You didn't post enough information to duplicate the problem. This is why I asked for an mcve (http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you Brian. After several tests with dummy keywords, I found out that the issue is with the code itself, not with the Test Template - when global variable is set, there won't be an error thrown. However, PyCharm (or at least the community edition) won't return the code line where the error is, therefore I assumed it's a Test Template issue. Could you suggest a better IDE I could use to write Robot scripts?