# What am I doing wrong here - loops in robot framework

Tags: for-loop, robotframework, iterable-unpacking

I have below code. It reads a csv file and create a list
csv file has just one line as of now, so list length would be 1.
I want to register user and details of user comes from the list. Ex.
demouser101,password01,firstname01,familyname01,1234567890'

I pass the list to "Register User" Keyword which unpacks it at argument level.
@{data_from_csv} looks like:

`[['demouser101', 'password01', 'firstname01', 'familyname01', '1234567890']]`

So I am using @{data_from_csv}[0].

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
TC_02 Register a Existing User Using CSV Data
        @{data_from_csv}=   Read CSV File      ${test_data_file}
        ${NUM}=  Get Length  ${data_from_csv}
        Log To Console      \n
        Log To Console      @{data_from_csv}[0]
        Go To Register Page
        Register User     @{data_from_csv}[0]
        Registration Should Fail

Register User
        [Arguments]     ${user}     ${pass}     ${fname}     ${lname}    ${ph_num}
        Scroll Element Into View    ${rp_username}
```

Logs show correct data:

```
TC_02 Register a Existing User Using CSV Data                         ...

.['demouser101', 'password01', 'firstname01', 'familyname01', '1234567890']
TC_02 Register a Existing User Using CSV Data                         | FAIL |
Keyword 'registerpage.Register User' expected 5 arguments, got 1.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ts 01 Registration Test :: Test Cases related to user registration    | FAIL |
> Blockquote
```

Comment: When I log @{data_from_csv} I see:
`[['demouser101', 'password01', 'firstname01', 'familyname01', '1234567890']]`

Comment: Apparently, below code works...

`@{data_from_csv}=   Read CSV File      ${test_data_file}
    : FOR   ${row}  IN  @{data_from_csv}
    \   Go To Register Page
    \   Register User     @{row}
    \   Registration Should Fail`
But this requires minimum one loop.. which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Try:
```Register User     @{@{data_from_csv}[0]}```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Read CSV File" returns a list of lists.
See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767791/how-to-feed-a-list-of-lists-as-an-argument-into-a-robot-framework-test-template) for how to use list of lists.
So you can either do:

```
Register User     @{data_from_csv[0]}
```

or change the keyword to:

```
Register User
    [Arguments]     @{data_list}
```